# MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem crashes on zoom in

Tags: ios7, navigation, tracking

I am using MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem to track user. I am not able to set the zoom when using user tracking bar button. So i tried to zoom in on the screen .
And application crashes after few steps.
I have a coordinate near by and i am trying to use this to keep track of user relative to the coordinates. 
Why is app crashing. 
Is there a better way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:-

```
 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

self.mapView.delegate = self;


_coordinate1.latitude = 29.9431438;
_coordinate1.longitude = -95.5170326;

 self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES; }


-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];


  MKCoordinateRegion region = [self regionFromLocations:self.currentLoc];

[self displayPoints];

MKCoordinateRegion adjustRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];

self.mapView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
[self.mapView setRegion:adjustRegion animated:YES]; }




- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
 MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *locateMeButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView];



NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: locateMeButton,
                         nil];
self.toolBar.items = toolbarItems; }





- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

NSLog(@"viewwillDisapear");

[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone];

[super viewWillDisappear:animated];}


-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
// getting current location
self.currentLoc = userLocation.location.coordinate;

NSLog(@"loc- %f   %f", self.currentLoc.longitude, self.currentLoc.latitude); }
```

Comment: What is the crash error message?

Comment: Surprisingly there is no error message. When i debug control goes to main.h  @autoreleasepool {...} and stays there in a loop.

Comment: You'll have to do some debugging with NSLogs, breakpoints, stepping through the code line-by-line, etc until you find out what line is causing the crash and why.  Try starting with this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by removing map view when view Disappear

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

```
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

self.mapView.delegate = nil;
[self.mapView removeFromSuperview];
```

}